# Pentaho CassandraInput slow response time

Tags: time, cassandra, response, pentaho, cql

I have a problem that affects the response time of the queries from CassandraInput. I use Datastax Enterprise 3.2.4 - Cassandra 1.2.13.2.
If I try to run the same query (any) directly from the Cassandra client, the answer is considerably faster than the same query executed on the node CassandraInput from Pentaho Data Integration.

What can cause this?
And above all, there is a way to improve the response time from the node CassandraInput in Pentaho?

I hope that some of you might have some suggestions.

Thank you

Federica

Answer (score 0):

Generally it has not to happen.

Try below thing and check whether performance in increasing or not.

open spoon.bat or spoon.sh file according to the OS you are using and change below thing. 
Below thing has to be change according to the size of the RAM of your Machine.

```
PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx2g"
```